# Scene Transition Fading But Not Switching Scenes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to transition from the default, root scene to a new scene with SpriteKit. However, whenever I press the Start button, it grays out the old scene (although it remains visible) and the Drawing Board label  shows up. The scene remains greyed out. All the buttons from the old scene can still be pressed but do not perform their associated actions. A UIButton triggers this func:

```
startButton.addTarget(self, action: "goToDrawingBoard:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

The func:

```
@objc func goToDrawingBoard(sender: UIButton){
    let drawingBoardScene = DrawingBoardScene(size: self.size)

    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(drawingBoardScene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))
}
```

And the DrawingBoardScene.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class DrawingBoardScene: SKScene {

    let titleLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "DRAWING BOARD")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {           
        /*LABEL: Displays title*/
        titleLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        titleLabel.fontSize = 60
        titleLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(titleLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough info to say for sure, but the optional chaining looks suspect: in `self.scene?.view?.presentScene`, if either `scene` or `view` is nil, `presentScene` won't be called. Is `goToDrawingBoard` in a class where it makes sense to chain that way? Have you tested the values of `self.scene` and `self.scene.view`?

Comment: goToDrawingBoard is in the MenuScene class

Comment: Check my second question. Also, the reason you're seeing the content of that scene even though you haven't transitioned is because you've added that scene as a child of the current scene. Either make a child or do a transition but don't do both.

Comment: Adding the child node doesn't actually affect the output, I just did to try it out. I've removed it now. However, per your suggestion, I tested self.scene and self.scene?.view and self.scene prints out name: '(null)' along with a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: If `self` is already a scene, you don't need `self.scene.view`. Just `self.view` should work.

Comment: True, but that isn't the problem. It's that self.scene is null. How would I fix that? I have a .swift file set up with a scene in it...

Comment: This code does not make sense,  1st,  why are you adding drawing scene as a child to a scene?   2nd self is suppose to be the scene?  then why are we calling another scene object, then this new scenes object view to present this?  This makes no sense.  You are presenting the child of an old scene to the new scene,  no wonder why it is failing.

Comment: I've updated it a bit to eliminate the extraneous stuff that I could. Sorry about the mess, I'm brand new to swift and spun myself in circles on this part.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are presenting the scene incorrectly,  try the following:

```
@objc func goToDrawingBoard(sender: UIButton){
    let drawingBoardScene = DrawingBoardScene(size: self.size)

    self.view?.presentScene(drawingBoardScene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))
}
```

There is no reason to add the new scene as a child to the old scene,  and who knows why your scene has a scene object.

As a personal note,  presenting your scene in this matter is not a good way to present scenes.  It is the views job to be presenting scenes, so what you should be doing is when it comes time for the scene to be removes, send a notification in some way to the view that the scene is done working and is waiting for it to be removed,  and have the view then present the scene.  This will allow the view to properly remove the old scene without having any retainers holding it back.  One method to do this is threw delegation

Comment: The code you have above is what I tried at first and it produces the same results I've gotten every time. The scene fades out and stays faded and the new scene overlays but does not replace the old scene.

Comment: what do you mean doesn't replace

Comment: are you saying the scene does die

Comment: I can still see the scene that was transitioned out of, but the parts where there are new labels, the new ones overlay the old ones.

Comment: that is where my personal note comes in then I am guessing

Comment: what is start button and where is it located

Comment: Do I have to remove the old scene? And how would this help with the scene remaining faded out? Start button is located just below the center of the screen, UIButton

Comment: you shouldn't have to manually remove it,  the transition should remove it for you,  but the problem is it can't remove it

Comment: /*BUTTON: Start button*/
        startButton.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        startButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Light", size: 30.0)
        startButton.frame = CGRect(x: (self.view!.frame.size.width/2)-50, y: (self.view!.frame.size.height/2)+50, width: 100, height: 50)
        startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: "goToDrawingBoard:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        
        self.view!.addSubview(startButton)

Comment: do not create UIView controls in SKScenes,  have your UIViewcontroller do this,  Think of the relationship like this  UIViewController is grandpa,  UIView(SKView) is daddy, and SKScene is the child,  the child should not be telling daddy what to do, and the daddy should not be telling grandpa what to do

Comment: So I want to be declaring all my UIButtons in the view controller and only have nodes in the scene files. That makes more sense. Should I be doing scene transitions in view controller as well?

Comment: if you do not have a class file for view, then yes, the view controller would be the next authority to be doing this,  if you do have a view class,  he can make buttons for himself also

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. One more question, would actions be in view class or scene class?

Comment: actions are played by nodes,  nodes are children of scene, so scene would tell nodes what to do

Comment: do not make this accepted LOL we do not know if this is even the issue yet

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I spent a couple nights working on various solutions and the one we finally came up with is this:

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
        self.removeAllChildren()
    delete(startButton)
}

override func delete(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let subviews = (self.view?.subviews)! as [UIView]
    for v in subviews {
        if let button = v as? UIButton {
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that when the scene shifts the buttons can take a split second longer to disappear, giving it a kind of glitchy feel. It does work though, so for a short term solution it is great.